# VB6 - Commondialog hide subfolder list

Tags: vb6, common-dialog

I would like to know if there is a manner for hide the subfolder listed in commondialog popup window so i can see only the files and not the subfolder

Comment: There is a .Flag cdlOFNNoChangeDir, but it doesn't do what you're asking (nor, in my opinion, what its name describes).  I didn't do a deep dive into the flags available for the Win32 API call to open a file dialog (GetOpenFileNameA, I believe), but a cursory look didn't show anything either.

However, you can build your own, using the Dir() function.  By setting the optional Attributes parameter to something not including the 0x10 bit, you'll get all the files not including directories; you can then use a ListBox on a form ( which you would .Show vbModal) to make your own file chooser.